# Can your webpack.config file serve multiple entry points?

Tags: angular, webpack

Due to learning Angular 2 while developing the project, I did not incorporate routing as well as I should have.  I have a main.js file that bootstraps one component, and another main2.js file that bootstraps a second component (I know now that I should have routed them from one page, but we are very far into the project that it will cause a backup ((will do if necessary however)).  I am trying to use webpack to bundle the code for 'loadability' (sp?).

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require( 'path' );
var webpack = require( 'webpack' );

module.exports = {
    entry: "./main",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts/, loaders: ['ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
};
```

Would it be possible to define two entry points like so:

```
var path = require( 'path' );
var webpack = require( 'webpack' );

module.exports = {
    entry: "./main",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts/, loaders: ['ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
};

module.exports = {
    entry: "./main2",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./dist/bundle2.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts/, loaders: ['ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
};
```

OR am I better off going back and re-structuring my project to use routing and have one entry point serve me components?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer, Yes.**

You can have multiple entry points and will generate multiple outputs if you want. 
The entry property could be a *string*, an *object* or an *array*.

**Example:**

```
var path = require( 'path' );
var webpack = require( 'webpack' );

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "main": "./main.ts",
        "main2": "./main2.ts",
    }
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    // Rest of your config ...
};
```

With `[name]` you will get the name of the entry point, *'main'* and 'main2' in your case, so you final bundles will be called *'main.js'* and *'main2.js'*

*Check this [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html) (is for webpack 1, but in webpack 2/3 is almost the same).*

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  This saves me from restructuring an entire project :)