# Calling Angular Component without calling root component

Tags: angular

I have built an Angular app in order to use in a tomcat production environment which works properly.

However, every time I use an angular component in my jsp pages I must load app-root first.

Is there any way to call directly a specific component in Angular without passing through the root component?

App-Root - Shop Component - Cart Component - Calc - Invoice

For instance: `<cart></cart>`

**UPDATED
@Mina Michael**

Your answer works! But this is not exactly what I am looking for (Maybe I am not taking the right approach.) I have two different modules each with a bootstrap component.

In my main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CounterModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

In my index.html I have both, this works! But If I stop the app and do "npm start or npm build" it crashes showing error in bootrstrapping... dont know why

```
<app-root></app-root>
<counter></counter>
```

Any idea?

Your solution is good but I need with the same app code be able to execute whatever component I need.

Comment: have you implemented the angular router  ?

Comment: @CruelEngine Yes, I have.

Comment: You want to load the components based on the url right ?

Comment: Not exactly, I have updated my question to detail it. I do use routing but it is hid from the url.

Comment: if your url changes for every component , then you can forward your request to index.html from the server end . So you won't face any 404 errors

Comment: I am not understanding what you are trying to explain me. I cannot modify any url on my project it is a struts 1 project. The only thing I need is to put in some of my jsp pages <component></component> and when I need routing in a component I do it transparently to the browser history.

Comment: Definitely, I found the solution. Look my answer. Many thanks! @CruelEngine

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your project was generated by angular-cli and the files follow the standard names.

In `index.html` replace `<app-root></app-root>` by `<cart></cart>`

---

In `app.module.ts`

1)  You'll find a line that imports "AppComponent"

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

remove it (or leave it) and import your cart component.

```
import {Cart} from './path/to/cart.component';
```

2) also add "Cart" to "declarations". You'll find this:

```
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
```

make it like this:

```
  declarations: [
    Cart,
```

3) also change this line

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

to be

```
bootstrap: [Cart]
```

And that should do it.

---

Another simpler way is to just open `app.component.html` and place Cart there instead of whatever is in there, like this:

```
<cart></cart>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Using webpack you can specficy multiply entrypoints.

In my case I have two modules AppModule and CounterModule which I want to call them independently.

I have created counter.ts file along with main.ts and referenced them in webpack.common.js file.

Now I can start my app either by calling app-root or counter tag.

Sources:

[Can your webpack.config file serve multiple entry points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045203/can-your-webpack-config-file-serve-multiple-entry-points)

https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html

Thanks for your effort guys!